# Google Earth or Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, web-applications, google-earth

I have 3 weeks to develop a prototype. Bascially a fleet management system, browser based. It will be tracking tractors in open country, using low data rate satellite modems to report vehicle location on a regular basis.

I am struggling to get a grip on whether I want to use Google Earth or Google Maps:

- ease of implementation (PHP/HTML 5, pulling data from a MySql database)
- tracking each vehicle, drawing a line, toggle display of time and/or distance travelled at each location
- visual appeal to user (given that it is open country, no real landmarks)
- available overlays (rainfall, temperature data, elevation, etc)
- anythign else?

I am toally at a loss on the mapping part (the reast I can do). Is one of Google Earth / Maps "best " **for me**? (not wanting to start a religious war)

Is it possible to use both and toggle between them?

Any other advice? I am googling like crazy and might not normally post this question before doing more research, but the dealine is ricdicuous. I am look at 16 hour days and need all of the help and advice that I can get. I will will have to live with the decision that I make now and I don't want to make a hasty one based on scant knowledge.

Thanks in advance...

---

[Update] oic. Google Earth is PC applicaion and Gogole maps is browser based. Well, I guess that that answers that, then.

---

[Update] Sigh! It's another of those where the head of the company uses an I-pad but the end users have Windows desktops. So he wants it browser based "just in case" he wants to look at it (which he might do twice in the first week and then never again). Why does it always seem to be this way?

Comment: Seven years later, I am using Leaflet and OSM (with AngularJs), and have been doing so since shortly after asking this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the right solution, you first need to identify your target audience for your app.

- Will the users of the web-based app be using desktops, iPads, or
  mobile devices that have Google Earth available?
- Will the intented users be using large screens located at the data center (Google Earth or Google Maps will work) or remote users in the field (Google Maps might be best better fit)?
- Not all mobile devices support the Google Earth application and the
  mobile devices have a limited feature set.
- Google Maps API, on the other hand, will run on nearly all web
  browsers for a multiple of devices.

See details:

1. Google Earth for Mobile
   http://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/mobile.html
2. Google Maps for Mobile
   http://www.google.com/mobile/maps/

Also note if you use [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/) you can easily mashup Earth and Maps in single web application but again this requires those platforms that support the Google Earth client.

Here's a sample demo to try out:
[image: Google Earth API Demo thumbnail]

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/drive-simulator/index.html

Comment: _1 and the answer. I am still trying to talk the project head away from browser (because he loves his Ipad) and towards a Windows app (because most of those who will use it have no Ipd, and becuase I feel that I can offer amore obust, more full-featured app for Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Future proof your application. It is my impression Google Earth is on it's way out. It is hardly maintained and with browser makers actively discouraging the use of these plugins it is only a matter of time.

If you choose to use the Google mapping tools, do have a close look at Google Maps. Although Google currently offers a 3D version of Google Maps, it is not yet available for application developers. We are still stuck with 2D maps.

However, I expect that the maps API will not change drastically once 3D applications are allowed.

I am a specialist in the use of Google Earth API (planetinaction.com) and I have shifted from Google Earth to Google Maps wherever possible.

As an intermediate solution, you could build a maps based app but allow a 3D view option by popping up a Google Earth plugin. this keeps Google Earth dependencies to a minimum.